# Requests: Module works locally but failed on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-requests, pythonanywhere

I am trying to make a twitter bot that uses requests library to get data from nytimes api.
There is a line in the code

```
resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, my_params)
```

Now this works very well when I run it locally. So I uploaded it to pythonanywhere. The moment I tried to run it I got this error:

> resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, my_params)
>   TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

What is happening? I have started using requests as well as pythonanywhere recently. So I have literally no idea where to start debugging.

Comment: Quick question: why have you unaccepted the answer. Is there anything missing in it?

Comment: Oh crap, I must've messed up while scrolling on the phone. Extremely sorry! The answer solved my issue. Nothing wrong with it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *different `requests` versions installed on PythonAnywhere and locally.*

---

From what I see `requests` version installed on PythonAnywhere is `2.4.0`. At that point, you had to [specify `params` keyword argument explicitly](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.4.3/api/?#requests.get):

> `requests.get(url, **kwargs)`

And you have to write:

```
resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params=my_params)
```

---

In the most recent version (`2.10.0` at the moment), you can have `params` specified [as a positional argument](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?#requests.get):

> `requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs)`

```
resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, my_params)
```

Comment: you can also upgrade requests on pythonanywhere if you like:  https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules  ,  https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
API_ENDPOINT = 'http://your_endpoint_url.com'

my_params = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} 

r = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params=my_params) # notice params is named named
```